# adding overlay to grid images on hover

Tags: html, css, grid, hover, overlay

I have an image gallery and would like to display text above it when hovering. I cannot set specific sizes to the image description because the grid resizes constantly. I know I could fix it with very specific media queries yet I don't want to do that. Is there a simple way for me to do it?

```css
.figure-img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.description {
    opacity: 0;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
}

.img-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

figure:hover .description {
    opacity: .8;
}

.d-name {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.d-item {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="figure3">
    <img class="figure-img" src="images/propg" alt="5St.">
    <div class="description text-center">
        <p class="d-name">Tower</p>
        <p class="d-item">Pnsulation</p>
        <p class="d-item">topping</p>
    </div>
</figure>

<figure class="figure4">
    <img class="figure-img" src="image" alt="nehandler">
    <div class="description text-center">
        <p class="d-name"> Tower</p>
        <p class="d-item">nsulation</p>
        <p class="d-item">topping</p>
    </div>
</figure>

<figure class="figure5 ">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="figure-img" src="images/pr34th-St%20rendering.jpg" alt="4h St">
        <figcaption class="description text-center">
            <p class="d-name"> Tower</p>
            <p class="d-item">PInsulation</p>
            <p class="d-item"> Firestopping</p>
        </figcaption>
    </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: when you hover can you see the text?

Comment: I could see it yet it's not positioned directly over the figure. it spreads across the entire main

Comment: So you want the description to be displayed over its corresponding image, or the entire gallery?